# Custom URL scheme does not work sometimes in iPhone

Tags: iphone, custom-url

I have an application where I have to get a message from server. The server sends the message in an SMS. Since iPhone applications cannot receive SMS programatically I have registered a Custom URL scheme and prefixing my message with the custom URL value say for ex: `mymsg://`.

This works fine most of the time. Whenever the SMS is received by the phone and I click reply button, it takes me to the reply state and the original message will appear like a link which I can click which takes me to the application. For some reason, sometimes this message is not clickable. That is, when I click on the message it does not launch the application or simply the message is not clickable. Then if i restart the phone, the link is clickable again and i can click on the link which launches my application. Does anyone know what could be the reason?

-chinnadurai

Comment: No one has faced a similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this issue before but I'm not sure it's the same one you're having. What I discovered is that whether or not a custom URL scheme is clickable in Messages.app is determined when the message *arrives*, not when the user sees the URL.

What this means is that if you send the user your custom scheme URL *before* they've downloaded the app, that link will never be clickable, even if they go on to download the app at a later time. I've verified this behavior on iOS 7.1 only (haven't checked other versions).

For my case, I can't guarantee that the user has already downloaded the app when I send the message, so my solution was to use a standard `http://` url that redirects to the custom `myapp://` URL on the server with a 302 redirect. Hope this helps!